# cPanel 7.9 - AutoSSL Not Working Properly

Tags: ssl, centos, cpanel

Hi I recently bought a VPS that is fully unmanaged.

Note: I changed my domain name to "mydomainexample.com". This is the only part which I changed.

As I do not have my own SSL Certificate, after installing Phusion Passenger and deploying a Node.JS (ExpressJs) Web Application on `mydomainexample.com/`, I proceed to cPanel > SSL/TLS Status and clicked on 'Run AutoSSL'.

However, the domain is still not secure and upon checking the Logs in WHM > Manage AutoSSL > Logs

I saw this:

```
Log for the AutoSSL run for all users: Thursday, April 21, 2022 6:16:20 AM GMT+0800 (cPanel (powered by Sectigo))
 6:16:20 AM AutoSSL’s configured provider is “cPanel (powered by Sectigo)”.
 This AutoSSL provider does not poll for certificate availability immediately after a certificate request submission. Instead, it submits certificate requests then periodically polls the cPanel Store for each requested certificate and installs it after a successful retrieval. The system will record all requests, retrievals, and installations for the current AutoSSL run in this log.
 Looking for potential NAT (Network Address Translation) problems …
 6:16:20 AM This server does not use NAT.
 6:16:20 AM Analyzing 1 user …
 6:16:20 AM Analyzing “snb”’s domains …
 6:16:20 AM Analyzing “mydomainexample.com” (website) …
 6:16:20 AM ERROR TLS Status: Defective
 Certificate expiry: 4/20/23, 9:08 PM UTC (364.95 days from now)
 ERROR Defect: OPENSSL_VERIFY: The certificate chain failed OpenSSL’s verification (0:18:DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT).
 6:16:20 AM Attempting to ensure the existence of necessary CAA records …
 6:16:20 AM No CAA records were created.
 6:16:20 AM Verifying 8 domains’ management status …
 Verifying “cPanel (powered by Sectigo)”’s authorization on 8 domains via DNS CAA records …
 6:16:20 AM “www.mydomainexample.com” is managed.
 “cpcalendars.mydomainexample.com” is managed.
 “cpcontacts.mydomainexample.com” is managed.
 6:16:21 AM “webmail.mydomainexample.com” is managed.
 “webdisk.mydomainexample.com” is managed.
 “cpanel.mydomainexample.com” is managed.
 “mail.mydomainexample.com” is managed.
 “mydomainexample.com” is managed.
 All of this user’s 8 domains are managed.
 CA authorized: “mydomainexample.com”
 CA authorized: “mail.mydomainexample.com”
 CA authorized: “webdisk.mydomainexample.com”
 CA authorized: “webmail.mydomainexample.com”
 CA authorized: “www.mydomainexample.com”
 CA authorized: “cpanel.mydomainexample.com”
 CA authorized: “cpcontacts.mydomainexample.com”
 CA authorized: “cpcalendars.mydomainexample.com”
 “cPanel (powered by Sectigo)” is authorized to issue certificates for 8 of this user’s 8 domains.
 6:16:21 AM Performing HTTP DCV (Domain Control Validation) on 8 domains …
 6:16:21 AM Local HTTP DCV OK: mydomainexample.com
 Local HTTP DCV OK: www.mydomainexample.com
 WARN Local HTTP DCV error (mail.mydomainexample.com): “mail.mydomainexample.com” does not resolve to any IP addresses on the internet.
 WARN Local HTTP DCV error (cpanel.mydomainexample.com): “cpanel.mydomainexample.com” does not resolve to any IP addresses on the internet.
 WARN Local HTTP DCV error (webdisk.mydomainexample.com): “webdisk.mydomainexample.com” does not resolve to any IP addresses on the internet.
 WARN Local HTTP DCV error (webmail.mydomainexample.com): “webmail.mydomainexample.com” does not resolve to any IP addresses on the internet.
 WARN Local HTTP DCV error (cpcontacts.mydomainexample.com): “cpcontacts.mydomainexample.com” does not resolve to any IP addresses on the internet.
 WARN Local HTTP DCV error (cpcalendars.mydomainexample.com): “cpcalendars.mydomainexample.com” does not resolve to any IP addresses on the internet.
 6:16:21 AM Verifying local authority for 6 domains …
 6:16:21 AM No local authority: “mail.mydomainexample.com”
 No local authority: “cpanel.mydomainexample.com”
 No local authority: “webdisk.mydomainexample.com”
 No local authority: “webmail.mydomainexample.com”
 No local authority: “cpcontacts.mydomainexample.com”
 No local authority: “cpcalendars.mydomainexample.com”
 6:16:21 AM No local DNS DCV is necessary.
 6:16:21 AM Processing “snb”’s local DCV results …
 6:16:21 AM Analyzing “mydomainexample.com”’s DCV results …
 6:16:21 AM AutoSSL will request a new certificate.
 6:16:21 AM The system will attempt to renew the SSL certificate for (mydomainexample.com: mydomainexample.com www.mydomainexample.com).
 6:16:25 AM The “cPanel (powered by Sectigo)” provider cannot currently accept incoming requests. The system will try again later.
 The system has completed “snb”’s AutoSSL check.
 6:16:25 AM The system finished checking 1 user.
```

There were 2 text highlighted red - I'm not sure what they mean:

```
6:16:20 AM ERROR TLS Status: Defective

ERROR Defect: OPENSSL_VERIFY: The certificate chain failed OpenSSL’s verification (0:18:DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT).
```

As I'm still a beginner in setting up servers I'm not really sure what to do. Could someone point me in the right direction?